# VB6 event passing bool argument that's always 'true' in C#

Tags: c#, events, vb6, marshalling, com-interop

My problem is simple, I have an event declared in a VB6 library that passes out a boolean argument:

```
Public Event WriteComplete(ByVal aCommsOk As Boolean, ByVal aBadPIN As Boolean)
```

I have hooked my c# code up to this event many times but bizarrely my testing department and a couple of other ppl have noticed that although VB6 raises this event with aBadPIN set to false, the c# event handler receives it as true. It is not consistent so it's one of 'those' problems but I'm not finding anything on the internet to help much.

I have found that if I define a new event that converts the bool to a byte and sends that, then it's converted back in the c#, this fixes the issue on those problem machines. However, I really don't want to have to do that since I would have to do it for every single bool that gets marshaled between my COM and .Net libraries (and there's a lot of them).

I also read somewhere that there's a known bug (at least in C++) where you have to force the EAX register to 255 to properly represent false but I've never had this problem before and frankly wouldn't know where to start doing that in VB6 anyway.

Any ideas would be great!

Update: Logging has shown that when this issue occurs the call that raises the event returns control to the VB6 code before the c# event handler fires. What is up with that?

Update: Still seeing event handler receiving event after the raising code has exited but tried marshaling changes to no avail. Time constraints will force me to add a wrapper sadly.

Comment: Posting the C# interop would be useful.

Comment: In VB 6, `false` is represented by 0 and `true` is represented by -1 (or NOT false). If you're either not marshaling the Boolean value correctly on the C# side, or checking it against the incorrect numeric literal, you're going to get the wrong result. Of course, as vcsjones says, this is impossible to debug unless you provide us with the rest of your code.

Comment: VB uses the VARIANT_BOOL type, which is a short (16 bits).  If you're marshalling this as 32 bits then False will appear as True if the other 16 bits are non-zero.  Are you doing any explicit marshalling or is COM interop handling everything?

Comment: COM interop is handling everything, there is none of my code in between.

Comment: The event is raised thus:

RaiseEvent WriteComplete(aCommsReceived, Not (aIsAcknowledged))

And arrives thus:

private void _MyObject_WriteComplete(bool aIsOk, bool aBadPIN)

aIsAcknowledged is true so false is passed but in aBadPIN arrives as true. 

I appreciate the differences in how bools are defined in these languages. I am unable to reproduce on my machine and my colleague who can at run time can't when debugging the VB6 code. So it must be an interop issue/bug and I'm fine with that if there is some sort of workaround that does not require me to wrap or extend my VB6 library.

Comment: @Akuma As in you just added a "reference" to the COM library?

Comment: @Akuma: VB6 Boolean operators are all bitwise; i.e. (Not 1) results in -2 not zero. Just saying, because you are using Not on the VB6 side.

Comment: Like @vcsjones said some code to look at would be nice. Also why can't you just convert the vb6 project to C#?

Answer (score 3):

Sorry that the problem wasn't as simple as bit-wise Boolean stuff in VB6 world.

If the problem is marshalling, is it possible that the interop DLL that .NET makes is somehow out of sync with its respective VB6 DLL? (As an aside, are you familiar with the Binary Compatibility settings in VB6?)

For the giggles, I did the following - please let me know if this simple set of projects is a representative model for the coding or marshalling issue you are tracking. If this issue is marshalling, it might be helpful to work it through  simplified versions of the c# and vb6 projects in tracking it down.

With VB6, I created a simple ActiveX DLL (project named LibBoolBuster), with a class called BoolBuster:

```
Public Event WriteComplete(ByVal aCommsOk As Boolean, ByVal aBadPIN As Boolean)

Public Sub DoIt(ByVal Mode As Integer)
    RaiseEvent WriteComplete(CBool(Mode And 1), CBool(Mode And 2))   
End Sub
```

With VS2003 (old .NET, but should still apply), I created a simple C# Windows app, having a form with four buttons, and making reference to the above VB6 ActiveX DLL. I made a member in the form that accesses the VB6 DLL:

```
public LibBoolBuster.BoolBuster vb6Obj = new LibBoolBuster.BoolBuster();
```

DLL via Interop is LibBoolBuster; class BoolBuster has event and DoIt member. In the form initialize, the event hookup is done like so:

```
vb6Obj.WriteComplete += new LibBoolBuster.__BoolBuster_WriteCompleteEventHandler(vb6Obj_WriteComplete);
```

The WriteComplete event handler is a member of the form:

```
private void vb6Obj_WriteComplete ( System.Boolean aCommsOk  , System.Boolean aBadPIN )
{
    MessageBox.Show(aCommsOk.ToString() + ", " + aBadPIN.ToString());           
}
```

Each button click event handler makes a simple call to DoIt:

```
vb6Obj.DoIt(0);
```

(and vb6Obj.DoIt(1), vb6Obj.DoIt(2), etc.)

Very simple project: Click a button, DoIt is called, event WriteComplete is fired. I gave it a try, and things worked as expected.

---

Take a close look on the VB6 side. You indicated the event is raised with:

```
RaiseEvent WriteComplete(aCommsReceived, Not (aIsAcknowledged))
```

Make sure that aIsAcknowledged is only either 0 or -1; otherwise you will not get the result you're expecting.

VB6 Boolean operators are all bitwise; i.e. (Not 1) results in -2 not zero.

Also, in VB6 any non-zero integer will be mapped to True when converting from Integer to Boolean - only zero becomes false.

Comment: Just to add to this, the fix would be to use `Not(CBool(aIsAcknowledged))`.

Comment: Well aIsAcknowledged is already a bool and has been logged at run time as true when this happens. Maybe the not conversion isn't wise to do when marshaling? I hadn't tried that but will tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: No sadly creating a bool locally and setting to false before returning it has the same effect so it's a marshaling issue.

Comment: I suspect because of the byte differences between VB6 bool and c# bool there is some uninitialized bits of information being marshaled instead of ignored and skewing the result. Perhaps if I try to convert the bool to byte then back before sending that will fix it? I'm clutching at straws now :)